# How to make this auto layout arrangement work with scrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout

I have a screen layout where there are two resizable labels , which will contain multiline text. These labels are placed inside their parent views which intern are added to main contentView, main contentView is then added to scrollView ( thats what most of the solutions suggests). For both the labels (below About and Time and location labels in first image attached) I have set height constraints as "greater than or equal to" and setting the numberOfLines to 0 as well as calling SizetoFit, but actual output is not as expected (see second image attached). There are no constraints warnings. All constraints are provided for all the elements.

[image]

[image]

The code in viewDidLoad is as follows for one of the label.

```
self.lblAbout.text = @"this is a long two three lines about string which will have two lines this is a long two three lines about string which will have two lines";
self.lblAbout.numberOfLines = 0;
[self.lblAbout sizeToFit];
[self.lblAbout setPreferredMaxLayoutWidth:244.0];
```

Also

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
 [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
 scrollView.contentSize = contentView.frame.size;
}
```

Not if any additional constraints are needed, I have added all leading , trailing , top , bottom constrains along with height wherever needed, plus the spacing between all the views is in place.
What i want is the labels should get adjusted to number of lines and the contentView (parent view) should scroll inside ScrollView as the total height will be larger than the screen available.

*** problem I think is the outer view of the labels aren't getting resized as per the label because of which all the views below it aren't getting repositioned ****

Comment: so the problem is that although you've set all the constraints, the scrolling doesn't work? or the resizing doesn't?

Comment: you are using scrollview with auto layout, hope my this answer will help u out for clearing ur concept of how to handle scrollView with auto layout http://stackoverflow.com/a/30804676/3767017\

Comment: @iosDev82 problem is twofold I think scrolling doesn't work because resizing isn't happening although I have set all the constraints I might be missing few more necessary ones , which I might. It be aware of.

Comment: @vishal Do you get the correct values for frame.size.height in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Comment: No, the scroll view content size results into very big scroll view

Comment: @iosDev82 please see above comment

Comment: Not sure why you need to try and manipulate the layout. If your constraints are correct it should all just work. I would remove your sizeToFit call and the viewDidLayoutSubviews code. No real point doing layout in `viewDidLoad` as no layout has happened anywhere yet. If anything call `[contentView setNeedLayout]` and `[contentView layoutIfNeeded]` in your `viewWillAppear` method.

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel i have a question about auto layout here will the outer view get resized if the labels extend beyond normal size ? coz that will automatically resize scrollview and things will work but the contentView which contains all the controls isn't getting resized and i m not sure it it will happen automatically

Comment: You might still need you viewWillLayoutSubviews code and to set the contentSize to `contentView.bounds.size`. You might find this useful: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel its there still doesn't work

Comment: Have you fixed the position of the UIScrollView itself? It should be pinned to the top layout, bottom layout, leading and trailing so it is forced to scroll?

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel yes and i tried setting some content i.e. height greater than contentView (which is inside scrollview ) and it scrolls, problem is the contentView doesn't resize as per change in height of labels

Comment: Something must be constraining the height of the content View. Would really need to see all your constraints. Perhaps create a cut down project and post it if you can.

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel bit difficult but will see if i can, it has 20 screens in a storyboard and i m short of time

Comment: If it is all done in storyboard, have you used the preview mode on the Assistant Editor to check if it looks correct? You can type in big labels and see how it would look when rendered on screen on different devices. Good way of seeing the effect of different constraint changes without needing to run.

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel I have checked even in emulator and once I place multi line text in label below About label it works fine resizes the view but pushes the next view which contains other labels below and under the other view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88795/discussion-between-rory-mckinnel-and-vishal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what worked finally.

1. Added ScrollView in main View
2. Added View as a contentView ( be sure to rename it in designer to something than just view )
3. pinned scrollview to main view using leading trailing top and bottom space constraints.
4. Pinned contentView to scrollview same as above
5. Added all the components with their respective constraints
6. Set the height of UILabel which i want to resize using "Greater than or equal to constraint (this is necessary) and set number of lines to 0 in code
7. The parent view of label shouldn't have any fixed height but enough constraints to calculate it at runtime.
8. Make sure ScrollView has no ambiguity in calculating contentSize.
9. *imp* - Add constraints to width of Main view , scrollview , contentView ( that was in my case , you may not need equal width constraint between contentView and scrollview , but between contentView and main view its necessary) 
   Now scrollview scrolls exactly the way it's needed. 
   To my belief most of the above things i already did but somehow it wasn't working ,deleted everything and did all the things again few times and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this Solution,

1. add Height Constraint to superView of your Label.

2. add IBOutlet of that Constraint

3. add this Method to find out Height of your Text
you need to give width of super view of your Label so width will be same as your super view

4. Now get Height form returned CGRect and assign it to your Constraints's constant. it should be like

```
heightConstraint.constant = youObject.size.height;
```

> > please Make sure you have added other Constraints accordingly this. if not than you need to also increase Height of other superviews accordingly.

```
(CGRect)sizeOfDetailLabelFromString:(NSString*)string maxWidth:(CGFloat)maxWidth{
NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName:FONT_LIGHT};
CGRect rect = [string boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(maxWidth, MAXFLOAT) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading attributes:attributes context:nil];
return rect;
}
```

Comment: I think increasing height of contentView which is a super view to all controls needs to be changed but since I have at least 8 different controls it seems difficult

Comment: so, for that just connect very superView's heightConstraints outlet and for that label's superview use can give Hugging priority, so basically logic is if extra space remains in superView than its subViews will get expand as per its need.

Comment: if you want than i can help you in adding constraints.

Comment: as far as size of label is concerned its getting adjusted actually ,its issue with superview of label , i am trying out few things thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88787/discussion-between-akash-soni-and-vishal).

Comment: ok, but as far as i got understand your UI I suggest you that just add top, bottom, trail, and leading constraints to label and its super view. and apply my solution to very super view of that label. so what ever height will increase according your text label will get space accordingly that.

Comment: point is contentView should resize automatically , and i m still looking for that solution , manually changing the heights of all superviews isn't a solution honestly .

Comment: for that I want to tell you one thing try to play with Hugging priority on that Label & views, I don't know exactly but it may get works.