# How to scroll the scrollview according to fields sizes in ios

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uiscrollview, autolayout

I am a beginner with Auto-Layouts for iOS. In my project, I programmatically add a UIScrollView on the View Controller, and I also added a Content View to said Scroll View.

After that, I added two auto-growing Text Views to the Content View. According to data size, Text Views sizes are growing them selves (i.e. the data for the Text Views is coming from services).

I want to scroll that Content View up so that two auto-growing Text Views are visible to the user on any iPhone/iPad screen (like 4, 5, 6, 6 Plus, iPad).

I have written some code but the Scroll View is not scrolling up to make all fields visible to the user. Could someone please help me?

And according to my code the screen appears like shown below and the remaining data is not visible to the user:

### AutoGrowingTextView:-

```
#import "AutoGrowingTextView.h"

@implementation AutoGrowingTextView

- (void) layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    if (!CGSizeEqualToSize(self.bounds.size, [self intrinsicContentSize])) {
        [self invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
    }
}

- (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize
{
    CGSize intrinsicContentSize = self.contentSize;

    // iOS 7.0+
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0f) {
        intrinsicContentSize.width += (self.textContainerInset.left + self.textContainerInset.right ) / 2.0f;
        intrinsicContentSize.height += (self.textContainerInset.top + self.textContainerInset.bottom) / 2.0f;
    }

    return intrinsicContentSize;
}

@end
```

### ViewController:-

```
  #import "ViewController.h"

    #import "AutoGrowingTextView.h"

    @interface ViewController ()

    {
        AutoGrowingTextView * TextView;

        AutoGrowingTextView * TextView1;

        UIScrollView * scrollView;

        UIView * containerView;

    }

    @end

    @implementation ViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad

    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];

        scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

        [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

        containerView = [[UIView alloc] init];

        containerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

        [scrollView addSubview:containerView];

        NSDictionary * views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(scrollView,containerView);

        [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[scrollView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

        [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[scrollView(600)]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

        TextView = [AutoGrowingTextView new];

        TextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

        TextView.text = @"De Villiers currently holds the record for the fastest 50, fastest 100 and fastest 150 in ODIs. The team that has suffered the most at the hands of this right-handed genius has been the West Indies.De Villiers currently holds the record for the fastest 50, fastest 100 and fastest 150 in ODIs. The team that has suffered the most at the hands of this right-handed genius has been the West Indies.De Villiers currently holds the record for the fastest 50, fastest 100 and fastest 150 in ODIs. The team that has suffered the most at the hands of this right-handed genius has been the West Indies.De Villiers currently holds the record for the fastest 50, fastest 100 and fastest 150 in ODIs. The team that has suffered the most at the hands of this right-handed genius has been the West Indies.De Villiers currently holds the record for the fastest 50, fastest 100 and fastest 150 in ODIs. The team that has suffered the most at the hands of this right-handed genius has been the West Indies.De Villiers currently holds the record for the fastest 50, fastest 100 and fastest 150 in ODIs. The team that has suffered the most at the hands of this right-handed genius has been the West Indies.De Villiers currently holds the record for the fastest 50, fastest 100 and fastest 150 in ODIs. The team that has suffered the most at the hands of this right-handed genius has been the West Indies.De Villiers currently holds the record for the fastest 50, fastest 100 and fastest 150 in ODIs. The team that has suffered the most at the hands of this right-handed genius has been the West Indies.De Villiers currently holds the record for the fastest 50, fastest 100 and fastest 150 in ODIs. The team that has suffered the most at the hands of this right-handed genius has been the West Indies.";

        TextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.95 green:0.47 blue:0.48 alpha:1.0];

        [containerView addSubview:TextView];

        TextView1 = [AutoGrowingTextView new];

        TextView1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

        TextView1.text = @"He smashed the fastest ODI off just 16 balls during the second ODI against West Indies in Johannesburg in January 2015. He had broken the 19-year mark off 17 balls set by Sanath Jayasuriya against Pakistan in Singapore in 1996.He smashed the fastest ODI off just 16 balls during the second ODI against West Indies in Johannesburg in January 2015. He had broken the 19-year mark off 17 balls set by Sanath Jayasuriya against Pakistan in Singapore in 1996.He smashed the fastest ODI off just 16 balls during the second ODI against West Indies in Johannesburg in January 2015. He had broken the 19-year mark off 17 balls set by Sanath Jayasuriya against Pakistan in Singapore in 1996.He smashed the fastest ODI off just 16 balls during the second ODI against West Indies in Johannesburg in January 2015. He had broken the 19-year mark off 17 balls set by Sanath Jayasuriya against Pakistan in Singapore in 1996.He smashed the fastest ODI off just 16 balls during the second ODI against West Indies in Johannesburg in January 2015. He had broken the 19-year mark off 17 balls set by Sanath Jayasuriya against Pakistan in Singapore in 1996.He smashed the fastest ODI off just 16 balls during the second ODI against West Indies in Johannesburg in January 2015. He had broken the 19-year mark off 17 balls set by Sanath Jayasuriya against Pakistan in Singapore in 1996.He smashed the fastest ODI off just 16 balls during the second ODI against West Indies in Johannesburg in January 2015. He had broken the 19-year mark off 17 balls set by Sanath Jayasuriya against Pakistan in Singapore in 1996.He smashed the fastest ODI off just 16 balls during the second ODI against West Indies in Johannesburg in January 2015. He had broken the 19-year mark off 17 balls set by Sanath Jayasuriya against Pakistan in Singapore in 1996.";

        TextView1.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.95 green:0.47 blue:0.48 alpha:1.0];

        [containerView addSubview:TextView1];

        //Applying autolayouts for textview1

        NSLayoutConstraint * constraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:TextView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:20.0f];

        [containerView addConstraint:constraint2];

        constraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:TextView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0f constant:5.0f];

        [containerView addConstraint:constraint2];

        constraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:TextView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0f constant:-5.0f];

        [containerView addConstraint:constraint2];

        //Applying autolayouts for textview2

        constraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:TextView1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: TextView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0f constant:20.0f];

        [containerView addConstraint:constraint2];

        constraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:TextView1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0f constant:5.0f];

        [containerView addConstraint:constraint2];

        constraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:TextView1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0f constant:-5.0f];

        [containerView addConstraint:constraint2];

        [scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[containerView(==scrollView)]|"
                                                                           options:0                                                                       metrics:nil
                                                                             views:views]];    

        [scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[containerView(==scrollView)]|"
                                                                           options:0
                                                                           metrics:nil                                                                         views:views]];
    }

    @end
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you want to enable scrolling as per your Content Size of String than refer this solution.
[How to make this auto layout arrangement work with scrollview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32395102/how-to-make-this-auto-layout-arrangement-work-with-scrollview/32395943)

Comment: This is not perfect solution for my queston