# How do I programatically set scrollView height to match content?

Tags: swift, constraints, scrollview

How do I make my `scrollView` height change dynamically to the content of the `view`? As it is now, I have set the `scrollView` height to a fixed value of 1600, but there is obviously a better way of solving this. I have created an `outlet` for the bottom constraint of the `scrollView` and one `outlet` for the bottom constraint of the content view. From there, I'm lost on how to actually set it up properly. To put it in plain text, I would like the `scrollView` constraint constant to be equal to where the content constraint is located. Something like this:

```
scrollViewHeightConstraint.secondAnchor?.constraint(equalTo: ingredientViewHeightConstraint.secondAnchor, constant: ingredientViewHeightConstraint.constant)
```

It's not working. And seeing that I don't actually understand what I'm doing here it's no surprise. I have looked around on the net and on `SO` but can't find a proper answer. Any thoughts?

***EDIT***
Trying to do this programatically, so suggested answer, although appreciated, is irrelevant.

Tried this:

```
scrollViewHeightConstraint.constant = self.view.frame.height + ingredientViewOutlet.frame.height
```

This makes the `scrollView` height equal to the `parent view` height + the content height (ingredientViewOutlet). It should definitely work in theory. Problem is, the compiler uses the static height of the ingredientViewOutlet, that is, its height before the height has actually been expanded by the content. If I can only use the dynamic height instead, the problem will be solved...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30794917/1630618

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you use auto layout in a scroll view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30794229/how-do-you-use-auto-layout-in-a-scroll-view)