# Understanding UIView Height When Constraints Are Set with AutoLayout/UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout

I hope this [image: this graphic] helps, but I am trying to wrap my head around a concept.  I have a UIScrollView, added to a self.view in my ViewController, with its top, leading, trailing, and bottom edges pinned to that of the self.view.  This is `viewA`.

I have a second UIView, `viewB`, with several subviews.  Each of those subviews are added to `viewB` with AutoLayout, and for brevity, each of those subviews have a height constraint set to a value.

I want to add `viewB` to `viewA`, with `viewA` able to scroll vertically.  Since `viewB` is undoubtedly taller than `viewA`, it should scroll.

I am adding `viewB` like so;

```
viewB.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewA.topAnchor).isActive = true
viewB.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewA.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
viewB.trailingAnchor.cosntraint(equalTo: viewA.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
```

This is where I am stuck.  If I set a bottom anchor (`viewB.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewA.bottomAnchor).isActive = true`), my UIScrollView does not scroll, and `viewB` is visibly cut off.

If I set a random height for `viewB` (using `viewB.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 2000.0).isActive = true`), the UIScrollView does scroll, though this constant is far too tall.

I am confused how to get the appropriate height for `viewB`.  Since `viewB` does have an actual height (with hard-coded subviews), I see no reason that AutoLayout shouldn't be able to calculate that height of `viewB`, even with no bottom anchor set, but can't figure out the right code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30794917/1630618

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- You need to hook viewB leading , trailing , top and bottom to viewA , plus width of viewB is set = width of main vc's view

2- all constraints inside viewB should be hooked properly from top to bottom

3- instead of repeatedly using `.isActive = true` consider wrapping all constraints inside `NSLayoutConstraint.activate([<#ConstraintsHere#>])`

4- May be for your current approach a `UITableView` is more suitable

Comment: Thanks for comment 1, fixed that in the post, that was a typo on my part.  On comment 3; how can I hook the lowest subview in `viewB` (in my case, Subview4) to its bottom anchor if it has a fixed height.

If Subview4 has `subview4.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1200.0).isActive = true`, would I also set a `subview4.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive=true` when adding it to viewB?

Comment: it's like a chain `subviews1`'s top constarint to `viewB`'s top , then bottom of `subview1` to top of `subview2` and so on until the last subview's bottom to bottom of `viewB`

Comment: Thanks, but how do I pin the bottom of subview4 to the bottom of viewB if subview4 also has a height?  Can I set both constraints?

Comment: off course you have to set both ,  the height gives the view it's content but the bottom makes the main viewB know it's accumulative height from all it's childrens that's how scroll happens

Comment: This has resolved my issue.  Thank you for clarifying.  Setting the `bottomAnchor` of `viewB`'s bottommost subview, even with its height constant, has allowed this work.  I will be posting a follow-up question as to how to update `viewA` if `viewB`'s height changes at any point.

Answer (score 1):

If the height constraint is complete, you don't have to consider viewA's contentSize. 
You don't need to use ViewB, subviews add to viewA, subview1's top equalTo viewA's top, set subview1 height, subview1's bottom equalTo subview2's top or offset some Height. And so on. Until the last subview, subview4's bottom equal to viewA' bottom. You can get a suitable content size without setting the height of the content.